# Systematic "This is our fault." on some links

Tags: bug, status-completed, error-message, broken-link, performance

It's unusual for me.

1. I go to [Performance questions about Generating Html Files from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981226/performance-questions-about-generating-html-files-from-database/3981282#3981282).
2. I tap on **harmen**'s username.
3. I'm directed to https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/176603/harmen with:

   > We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. **This is our fault.** Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified.

---

Actually, now most links on Stack Overflow are returning me an error: I can hardly browse at all.

- My own profile is returning https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/1033581/c%C5%93ur
- Questions tab is returning https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions

[image]

Comment: @ivarni Now I can't use Stack Overflow at all. Only Meta.

Comment: It's down for me also not able to use it https://twitter.com/arasuvel001/status/966950632400871424

Comment: Just for the record: I have been seeing odd search results (tag search on c#  showing no records for example) the last few days. It happens intermittently. I mentioned it in the Tavern but did not get confirmation if they found a root cause. Last night [Marc Gravell mentioned cache issues](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6714154#6714154) and loves to hear about it. The site and the specific pages are working atm for me (I'm in western-europe, in case it matters).

Comment: And I just repro-ed it (8:51 UTC) on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507332/hide-function-parameters-not-working-in-jquery#comment84885733_37507332)

Comment: @LGSon That's interesting, everything is working for me from Norway. I'm not sure how SO does load balancing but if there's a faulty server or two maybe clearing out cookies help getting to another node?

Comment: @ivarni Starting to get better here now... :) ... w/o clearing cookies

Comment: I'm getting the same error on the android tag and a specific topic, the site itself seems to work

Comment: I can't reproduce with the specific links, but it seems random. At one point I got an error message telling me there was maintenance, then the "this is our fault". It doesn't seem to be related to specific links, but I can reproduce it from time to time. Comments don't work properly either, the inbox (and all of this is random, it doesn't always happen).

Comment: I got / get this error when I want(ed) to login or ask a question. I did need more than five tries to login.

Comment: Singapore is having sporadic errors.  The push notifications for comments and rep to my phone seem unaffected, but page downloads are 50-50.  I'm losing points here, please fix this!

Comment: Apparently a world-wide problem. Guess we'll have to wait til the US-based staff wakes up and fixes it :)

Comment: Same in Moscow/Russia. Surprisingly, some links failed, then one worked, and now that one is failing too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are a couple of servers gone haywire which are put in and out of rotation by the load-balancer.

Comment: For me some links are giving this error (India). "We apologize for any inconvenience, but an unexpected error occurred while you were browsing our site. It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault. Detailed information about this error has automatically been recorded and we have been notified."

Comment: Happy note :) Member for 46 days, I've never seen the site fall. Works very very well most of the time. Thanks for this great site and great community.

Comment: Maybe they just want us to see the new updated error page. The new image looks cool btw

Comment: I just had this on 4 out of 5 questions opened. I cannot even vote to close

Comment: @Syscall to be fair, it's rare that the site falls over like this without warning, eg 'We're testing failovers/backups/whatever' first.  Usually it breaks because they broke it:)

Comment: The problem is clearly the new page with the dead robot. Previously you got a picture of a sysadmin cat who was ["workin on ur problemz"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/06/23/workin-on-ur-problemz/). The cat has been fired and thus nobody is working to fix this.

Comment: Seems OK again @ 10:29 GMT in UK.  I have the error, but very imtermittently.  Mostly OK ATM.....  Just close-voted 2 Q's without error.

Comment: It is happening right now. Mostly when I click on related Questions.

Comment: status:https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/966987353301639169

Comment: Its Working for me in India ,i am redirected to 
 his profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/176603/harmen

Comment: Hm, it's back again.. Well, another pizza :) Well, can't you guys in SO team just throw out those ill servers and before the startup test them?

Comment: Yeah, I get timeouts on posting comments again, just like earlier today.

Comment: I'm still getting redirected to this error page on CodeReview and SO as of right now.

Comment: Ok, this apparently got fixed 5 minutes after I wrote my comment, so that's good.

Comment: I'm looking for a dev now that can shine some light on this. Sorry for the crickets from us on this one folks.

Comment: Live footage of the investigation and work being done to fix this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJOlp.gif

Comment: Mobile site is on.

Comment: Still seeing some failures on desktop, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444785/341065  Chicago area.

Comment: 'It’s not you, it’s us. This is our fault.' at 11:12 GMT, UK.   Others on SOCVR also experiencing problems: error, slow load etc.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I unfortunately don't have an awesome answer here. We don't have an exhaustive list of contributing factors yet. I woke up to a server farm on fire as well. I'll share what we know, it's all I've got.

There were 2 web servers (of 9) affected. `ny-web01` and `ny-web04` exhausted connection pool capacity to Stack Overflow's database by many orders of magnitude. When this happens at our scale, it's impossible (mathematically) to recover from on a particular server (without halting traffic).

Some context for below:

- Stack Overflow runs on 9 web servers
- Each one handles 200-500 requests/sec at the time of day this occured
- All requests for the Q&A network are handled by a single application pool

#### What kept the application down

What happens in this situation is requests in the IIS queue (from HAProxy) need a thread from the pool. These then go to waiting behind the connection pool acquisition queue upon the first database call (we re-use 1 DB context for the lifetime of a request). At a per-server volume of 200-500 requests/sec average this time of day, you eventually get to thread pool starvation in IIS and `async` (or any other) continuations stop happening.

The reason this happens is let's say we have a request doing work. It has done a database query and is waiting to handle the result. This task requires a completion thread, of which we have a finite amount. It looks like this:

```
Request -> DB Query -> SQL Server -> (data in buffer) -> (please sir may I have a thread?)
```

But, we don't have a thread. Because all of those requests from IIS have now exhausted the thread pool at our traffic per server volume. Almost every new thread available as the pool grows (which is very slowly) is being eaten by the next request in queue. All of the database calls (or any awaiter) in flight are waiting a very long time on a thread. During this time, they are occupying one of the connections in the pool. New requests are waiting on the pool and old requests are blocked by the new request (stolen threads) from finishing.

We now have a deadlock situation. In theory, less traffic or faster thread pool growth would resolve this, but less traffic didn't happen (I'll get to that) and faster thread pool growth isn't very controllable (and doing so is very dicey).

Most of the time efficiency (lots of requests on few servers) is awesome. In this situation it isn't. It exacerbates the problem.

#### What went wrong with our load balancer

So you saw a robot, why the hell didn't HAProxy take those 2 servers out of rotation before I did? Well, because ASP.NET errors redirect to `/error` in the world we're in (we're not on ASP.NET Core yet...we're working towards it). This means HAProxy gets a 302 back, it interprets this as "success". It only removes the server when things get *really* bad and all those queues I talked about back up to the network layer and HAProxy <-> IIS timeouts occur.

There is a fix for this, we can tell HAProxy to *only* expect certain status codes (it's a regex setting), and it should know that our home page should never redirect. This is something I added the ability for in puppet months ago but never found the time to deploy. The priority just went up and I'll make sure this goes live next week.

#### What triggered this?

This is the part we're still digging on. You can see from this SQL connection graph per server *something* is causing a connection explosion (per app pool) intermittently:

[image: SQL Connections]

While it may seem obvious that "something is opening up a lot of connections" it only *appears* to be a root cause. When we get a lot of SQL connection pool timeouts in the log this is a developer's natural first assumption. But that's misleading.

Remember above when we covered all the queues ultimately in play? Now imagine a stall across requests at *any* point in the pipeline. Ultimately you'd end up with a bunch of requests at the IIS/app pool front door waiting to charge in like an angry mob. There are various reasons this could happen. It could be a network hiccup, or a dependency failover, or a stall in a dependent service, or time spent in a locked section of code. Or more likely for us: time spent in garbage collection. We don't see evidence of that directly here but it's also very hard to diagnose due to GC being a pay-the-piper after the fact order. Correlating requests and causation isn't trivial and requires a lot of digging.

So we still have unknowns. We're working on it, I just wanted to give an update here since this was a very visible outage I strive to keep you away from.

I'm sorry we had a bad day and hope it didn't inconvenience anyone too much. We'll do better.

**Update**: I'm marking this complete as the HAProxy fix was deployed that week - going forward web servers will be summarily terminated without due process if they step out of line. We're harsh, but fair.

Comment: Is it actually on fire or is that a metaphor?

Comment: I think it is awesome to be given this level of insight into these issues. As a user it is comforting to see the level of response and as a developer it is interesting to get a glimpse of the process.

Comment: @csmckelvey I remember seeing a write up or two from amazon about major aws issues. An even bigger scale than SO. Always interesting to see stuff at huge scales like this.

Comment: Reminds me of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp0_on_fire

Comment: @Azor-Ahai we don't have a webcam in the cage these servers are in, but an actual fire might explain at least 2 things.

Comment: Why isn't that ASP.NET error redirect *disabled*?

Comment: Why are the servers in a cage? Did they do something wrong? Did they have fair trial?

Comment: @ShadowWizard: that would be to protect them from the mentioned angry mobs.

Comment: @ShadowWizard cause they get bitey sometimes.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek  can't blame them, with such overload they're really hungry.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's an image I don't ordinarily associate with the denizens of our datacenters.  I should create a photoshopped image with teeth.... thanks for the morning chuckle!

Comment: Err.  Sorry, but the first sentence is wrong.  You *do* have an awesome answer.

Answer (score 6):

Note that once you receive the error, you're redirected to those weirdo URLs:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/users/176603/harmen
```

When this happens, you can't just refresh the page. You have to either *go back* and click on the link again, or you need to delete out the `error?aspxerrorpath=/` part to get back the real URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/176603/harmen
```

Even trying again immediately will often allow it to load. If you're not doing this, then you'll get a lot more "errors."

Comment: I've tried refreshing many opened tabs after an error recovery, and I've kept getting errors. (I use Safari and it doesn't display the path after the domain by default). It took me long before I've realized that I was actually refreshing the error page. I think it should be on SO's todo list to keep the URL the same instead of redirecting to an error page, for a better UX.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu 6 to 8 weeks* ;)  Although personally, I think the meme should be changed to 6 to 8 *years*! (* See [this meta](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514))

Comment: Yeah this is annoying. IMO it should be a 500 response without a `Location` header, with the response content as now

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit blame ASP.NET.

Comment: @Braiam: Done, as requested.

Comment: @Braiam or IIS.  I really want to blame Chrome and/or SAP, but I guess that's a stretch..